# what is the Question feed link on right bottom of the page doing?

Tags: discussion

I am fairly new and still discovering functionalities.

I wonder what is this question feed link doing? i wanted to follow a question without having to mark it as favourite. when i click on this question feed i get a new tab with a xml structure in it.

[image]

Comment: Check if this could help you [RSS feed of your favorite tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags?rq=1)